# Ionic Auth - how to retrieve data of all users?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

I use the standard Ionic Auth for user authentication, which means that all user details are stored in Ionic Cloud.

How it is possible to get (retrieve) details of all users and use them in my app?
Because now I am able get just current user details, for example email address via *$ionicUser.details.email*

Use case 1 - I would like to list all registered users 
Use case 2 - All users have custom field "group" with group name. On different page, I would like to list all users who are members of the same group as current user.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

To list all ionic auth users send an autenticated request to the cloud api endpoint at "/users" (see http://docs.ionic.io/api/endpoints/auth.html for other options).